# Any suggestions to scrape twitter profiles age using pyhthon

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I am rn trying to scrape twitter for an nlp research. I already used snscrape to get tweets with the required filters, the issue is that we need tweets from  a specific age range. In my head I guess some profiles on twitter have their birthdate public, so maybe we can fetch that. Maybe webscrape that from the profile? Any ideas are welcomed.

Till now I have tried some methods of webscraping but can't find something concrete

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has a pretty well documented API that works very well with Python.
Try to make a simple crawler and see one of the JSONs that you get for a Tweet/User.

You will need to sign up and get some Access Tokens/Keys to use in your script, but other than that you are ready to go:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api

Answer (score 0):

The age of Twitter users is not made available via the API (and the website may show birthday but not year). There are also [a number of other factors](https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/more-on-restricted-use-cases) you should read about in relation to analysis of Twitter user data.